# Finding child views from parent view created programmatically in Android

Tags: android, view

For an Android App, I'm using a GridView and extending BaseAdapter to organize its contents.  For the function getView that I override in my extended BaseAdapter class, I create a LinearLayout, which I attach an ImageView and 3 TextViews to.  Now, I need to implement convertView, but because I created my views programmatically, I didn't think I can use findViewById to find these child views to change their properties (like text and bitmaps).

I had the idea of assigning a unique ID pertaining to different types of views for each one when I create them (example: give my name textview the id of 1, description textview the id of 2, etc), but I was not sure if the ids have to be unique among every view, whether they're the same kind of view or not.

Ultimately, how do I find a child view that's part of a linearlayout view which were all created programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get children of LinearLayout via [`getChildAt()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29) but it's hard to distinguish what child exactly you get.

I think assigning IDs is better way. You can assign IDs to your views and later get views via `findViewById()`. IDs doesn't need to be unique for each LinearLayout.

Something like this:

```
// Give more sensible names to ID's
int IMAGEVIEW_ID = 0;
int TEXTVIEW1_ID = 1;
int TEXTVIEW2_ID = 2;
int TEXTVIEW3_ID = 3;

imageView.setId(IMAGEVIEW_ID);
textView1.setId(TEXTVIEW1_ID);
textView2.setId(TEXTVIEW2_ID);
textView3.setId(TEXTVIEW3_ID);

...
// somewhere later
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(IMAGEVIEW_ID);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, no more out of memory errors for not reusing my views!.  I was also disappointed I can't create enumerators the same way I can in c++ and assign them values, so I just created a nested class with final static int VIEWNAME and assigned them numbers.

Comment: @Sergey Glotov: what does that "convertView" refer to here. and I tried the same but getting a null. can u help me pls(tried it for "LinearLayout")

Comment: @kAnNaN `convertView` is parameter of adapter's `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method

Comment: Rather than hardcoding id numbers, you could instead use [`View.generateViewId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId()) which will _Generate a value suitable for use in setId(int). This value will not collide with ID values generated at build time by aapt for R.id._