# Want to make button that grabs values from dynamicaly created editTexts

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to have my submit button take the values of the editTexts that were created, but since they dont have names and I dont know how many of them there will be I dont know how to go about grabbing all of them from the button. ANy help or tips would be appreciated!

```
LinearLayout arrowSubmissions = findViewById(R.id.arrow_submissions);
        for(int i = 0; i < arrows; i++){
            EditText submission = new EditText(this);
            submission.setHint(String.format("%d", i  + 1));
            arrowSubmissions.addView(submission);

            Button sbmtButton = findViewById(R.id.submit_button);
            
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding child views from parent view created programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550772/finding-child-views-from-parent-view-created-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using an arrya of EditTexts that I just used a getText from to set the values.